# AngularJS - conditional formatting using a filter

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to apply conditional filltering in my html using an Angular filter:

Filter in JS file:

```
angular.module('myFilter', []).filter('conditionFormat', function () {
    return function (input) {
        return (input 
            ? '<span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is true</span>' 
            : '<span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is <span style="color: #FF0000;">NOT</span> true</span>');
    };
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<td>
  <span ng-bind-html="{{statement.IsTrue | conditionFormat}}"></span>
</td>
```

The output of this is literally:

```
<span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is true</span>
```

Is there a way to encode the return string in HTML? or perhaps another way of accomplishing this?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ng-switch appears to have worked well.

HTML:

```
<td>                                      
   <div ng-switch on="statement.IsTrue">
      <div ng-switch-when="true"><span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is true</span></div>
      <div ng-switch-when="false"><span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is <span style="color: #FF0000;">NOT</span> true</span></div>
      <div ng-switch-default><span style="color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-weight: bold;">No answer selected</span></div>
    </div>                                            
</td>
```

Answer (score 4):

It would be cleaner to do this using CSS classes and [ngClass](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClass):

```
<span class="normal">The statement is </span>
<span ng-class="{warn:statement.IsTrue}">{{statement.IsTrue}}</span>
```

With appropriate definitions for the CSS classes 'normal' and 'warn'.

Alternatively, just use [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angHide) and ngHide to show one block of HTML and to hide the other.  For the most part, in Angular, you manipulate a model and the view renders it using conditional directives; you rarely need to manipulate the HTML directly.

Answer (score 2):

I think a `directive` is a better way to achieve what you want, because you need to generate html based on some value, the best use of a filter however is to just **format** the output.

Here is an example:

JS

```
angular.module('myDir', []).
  directive('truthful', function() {
    return function(scope, element) {
      function updateUi() {
        if (scope.isTrue) { //NOTE: change to whatever you have in your scope
          element.html('<span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is true</span>');
        }
        else {
          element.html('<span style="color:#008000; font-weight:bold;">The statement is <span style="color: #FF0000;">NOT</span> true</span>');
        }
      }

      scope.$watch('isTrue', updateUi);
    };
  });
```

HTML

```
<span truthful></span>
```

I have also created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/72Zb3U) for you to take look.